# Does ClassName in python refer to two objects?

Tags: python

Consider a simple class:

```
class A:
   a=98
```

When I define the class A ,'type' class will create an object which will be our class,since 'type' is the metaclass.Now,according to python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html),when we leave the class definition(via the end),a *class object* is created and that object is binded to *ClassName* which is A in our case. So does name 'A' refer to two objects i) object created by 'type' metaclass which is the class itself ii)*class object* ?

If A refers to *class object* then which name refers the object created by 'type' metaclass or the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

The *class* (object) and *type* are the same thing in Python 3 (which documentation you quoted), so in your example `A` is the class that `type` created. You can call `A` a type or a class, but it is the same object.

In the Python 3 documentation you link to we also read:

> Each value is an object, and therefore has a *class* (also called its *type*). It is stored as `object.__class__`.

...asserting both terms refer to the same thing. See also the following quote from that documentation:

> Use `isinstance()` to check an instance’s type: `isinstance(obj, int)` will be `True` only if `obj.__class__` is `int` or some class derived from `int`.